# Not able to upload my apk to play store

Tags: android, upload, google-play

I am trying to upload my apk to google play store. Actually I am updating my apk with new version. I've changed version code, version number, used same package name and signed with same keystore file. Even though I am facing problem with my apk upload.

When tried to upload my apk to the market, I got this message:

UPLOAD NEW APK TO PRODUCTION

Upload Failed

You Need to use different package name because "com.xxx.xxx.xxx" already exists in Google Play

Comment: Is it signed with same keystore? Are you updating the build and not uploading it as a new app?

Comment: yes it is signed with same keystore file.

Comment: have you used your own keystore or debug keystore ?

Comment: You Need to use different package name because "com.xxx.xxx.xxx" already exists in Google Play !!

Comment: but i've uploaded my before versions(nearly 5 versions) with the same package name.@jenuine

Comment: Yes, I've used same and my own keystore or debug keystore @ParmarS

Comment: I've used same application package name. But I've changed my sub package names. Is it important to have same sub package names too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are uploading APK as a new android app. Go to publisher site than select your app -> APK -> upload new APK to Production.

[image: Upload new Android Apk on Google Play]